# Rubyで小数点以下の数字が0の場合は削除したいのですがよい方法はありますか？

Tags: ruby

以下のような値にしたいです
10.0 →10
1.5→1.5

以下のような処理でvalue=1.0ではなく、value=1となるようにはなったのですが、
もっと良い方法はありますでしょうか？

```
value = 10.0 / 10（何らかの計算）
if value == value.to_i
  value = value.to_i
end
```

Comment: 小数点以下を除いて出力したいという話ではなく、`value` を浮動小数点数から整数にしたいということで合っていますでしょうか？

Comment: Rubyの数値型には大きく分けて浮動小数点型(`Float`)と整数型(`Integer`)があり、浮動小数点型を特に書式化せずに出力させると、たとえ値が整数値でも「これは浮動小数点型の値ですよ」と言う意味で`.0`が付加されるようになっています。あたなのやりたいのは「①浮動小数点型のまま、表示の際に(整数値であれば)`.0`を出力しないようにする」なのか、または「②値の型を浮動小数点型から整数型に変換してしまう」なのか、どちらでしょうか?現在のあなたのコードは「値が整数値の場合だけ②の処理を行う」ものになっています。

Comment: お二方様、コメントありがとうございます。
OOPerさまの言うところの「表示の際に(整数値であれば).0を出力しないようにする」になります。
計算は浮動小数点の型で行い、計算結果が整数で表せるものであれば、小数点以下の「0」を消したいと思っています。
最終的にはstring型にしたいと思っているため、
整数値と一致する（小数点以下がない場合だけ）if文の処理を通らせている状態になります。

Answer (score 4):

コメントにあるように「計算は浮動小数点の型で行い、計算結果が整数で表せるものであれば、小数点以下の「0」を消したい」「最終的にはstring型にしたい」と言うことであれば、表示、あるいは文字列への変換の際に書式指定をしてやるのが良いでしょう。

```
irb(main):008:0> value = 10.0 / 10
=> 1.0
irb(main):009:0> str_value = "%.15g"%value
=> "1"
irb(main):010:0> print(str_value)
1=> nil
irb(main):011:0>
```

実行例はirbによるものなので、`=> 式の値`なんて余計なものが付いていますが、文字列型の`str_value`の値には、`.0`なんて含まれていないのは確認いただけると思います。

`to_s`でデフォルトの書式で文字列化してしまうと希望通りの文字列にならないことはよくありますが、その場合には数値型のまま値をいじってなんとかしようなんて思わずに、さっさと書式を指定した方が良いですね。

Answer (score 1):

`ActiveSupport`を使った方法はどうでしょうか。

```
require "active_support"
require "active_support/number_helper"

ActiveSupport::NumberHelper.number_to_rounded(1.0, strip_insignificant_zeros: true)
#=> "1"
ActiveSupport::NumberHelper.number_to_rounded(1.5, strip_insignificant_zeros: true)
#=> "1.5"
```

https://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/4.0.0/ActiveSupport%2FNumberHelper:number_to_rounded